# TinyMCE in Wordpress automatically decoding to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want `&#91;` instead `[` and `&#93;` instead `]` in my wordpress text editor.
I am inserting it from a modal textarea.
which encodes to html entities before inserting it in wordpress editor.

code for encoding is :

```
String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g,'&#34;').replace(/'/g,'&#039;');
```

I tried following:

1. `.replace(/\[/g,'&#91;')` but editor shows  `&amp;#91` in `text` view instead of `&#91;`
2. If I manually enter `&#91;` in `text` view it automatically gets converted to `[` while switching between `visual` and `text` views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, that's because you are transforming all `&`'s to `&amp;` before you do so for `&#91`. That means at the moment the conversion for the accolade kicks in, it finds no accolades `&#91` because there are none, this part `amp;` has gotten in between everywhere.

Simply cut paste `.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')` to the end of your `replace` chain and it should work.